# C# interop word paragraph spacing won't change

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am building a program that builds a Word document from scratch. All went really well, but I can't get past a certain bug. The problem I face is that I have a paragraph and I want to set the Space Before to a certain value, but when I build the document the paragraph appears with all my settings except for the right space before. See my code below

```
Paragraph Bijlage = document.Paragraphs.Add();
var t = Bijlage.Parent;
t.Paragraphs.LineSpacingRule = WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
Bijlage.Format.SpaceBefore = 9;
Bijlage.Range.Font.Name = "CharterITC BT";
Bijlage.Range.Font.Size = 13;
Bijlage.Range.Font.Spacing = 2.85f;
Bijlage.Range.Text = "Bijlage";
```

So the font size and everything works except for the line `Bijlage.Format.SpaceBefore = 9`

In the document it stays 0

Does anybody have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I had similar problem with alignment in paragraphs. The thing there was that u had to set Alignment AFTER you set the text property. You can try it maybe it's the same problem ;)

Comment: @eren I confirm - that's the issue.